# why would return statement before cosole.log affect the whole function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have written the following script which is supposed to calculate half of a number, the square root of it, the area of a circle and percentage of both square root and area.

However, when I wrote the script I used the return statement followed by console.log() in the execution space, when I did this syntax error occured but when I declare a console.log() first followed by return, the code seems to work fine.

Here is my Code.

***Good Code:***

```
function squareNumber(num){
    var squaredNumber = num * num;
    console.log(" the square of " + num + " is " + squaredNumber);
    return squaredNumber;
}


function halfOf(num){
    var half = num / 2;
    console.log(" half of  " + num + " is " + half);
    return half;
}

function percentOf(num1, num2){

    var percent = (num1 / num2) * 100;

    console.log(num1 + " is " + percent + " % of " + num2);
    return percent; 
}


function areaOfCircle(radius){
    var area = 3.14 * radius * radius;

    console.log(" the area of a circle with radius of " + radius + " is  " + area);
    return area;

}

function doCrazyStuff(num){
    var halfy = halfOf(num);
    var squared = squareNumber(halfy);
    var area = areaOfCircle(squared);
    var result = percentOf(area, squared);

}
```

***Bad Code:***

```
function squareNumber(num){
    var squaredNumber = num * num;
    return squaredNumber;
    console.log("the square of " + num + " is " + squaredNumber);

}


function halfOf(num){
    var half = num / 2;
    return half;
    console.log(" half of  " + num + " is " + half);
}

function percentOf(num1, num2){

    var percent = (num1 / num2) * 100;
    return percent;
    console.log(num1 + " is  " + percent + " % of " + num2); 
}


function areaOfCircle(radius){
    var area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
    return area;
    console.log(" the area of a circle with radius of " + radius + " is " + area);

}

function doCrazyStuff(num){
    var halfy = halfOf(num);
    var squared = squareNumber(halfy);
    var area = areaOfCircle(squared);
    var result = percentOf(area, squared);

}
```

Comment: *"Syntax error"* ? Are you sure? Having code after the return makes no sense but it's not a syntax error.

Comment: What was the specific syntax error?  Putting statements after return shouldn't cause an error, though it won't run the code.

Comment: `syntax error occured` - which browser tells you it's a syntax error? firefox simply *warns* you about unreachable code - but it all works (excluding the code after return of course)

Comment: sorry I am a begginer, I meant it it return "undefined" in Chrome not syntax error.

the function won't even execute, I thought it should execute; stopping at the return statement and ignoring the console.log() in the "bad code", but it didn't function at all.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't function at all? With the log statements moved to after the returns there will be no visible output from any of your functions. doCrazyStuff() puts the results in variables, but they're not logged and doCrazyStuff() returns undefined (by default, because it has no return statement).

Comment: I see, so what would be the effect of not using return at all in the execution space?

You were very helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: Your doCrazyStuff() function doesn't need a return statement, but after it calls the other functions it needs to do *something* with the results if you want to see them, whether that be logging those four variables to the console, or displaying the values in the page (assuming you're running that code in a browser), or...

Comment: ok I got it now, thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

return stops the function execution and nothing else is executed after it.

Do not put code after return statements in any language.